# Warning: Attempt to read property "nums_row" on bool in

Tags: php

llevo revisando una plantilla web que estoy modificando parcialmente para propositos de estudio personal y me he encontrado con este error:

Warning: Attempt to read property "nums_row" on bool... line 16

Es un servicio web de pedidos muy simple que filtra por busqueda conectado a una base de datos, el error me aparece en concreto para el archivo php orders.php y el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include("database.php");
class orders extends database
{
    public $mysqli;
    public $counter;
    
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->mysqli = $this->conectar();
    }
    
    public function countAll($sql)
    {
        $query = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        $count = $query->nums_row;
        return $count;
    }
    
    public function getData($tables, $campos, $search)
    {
        $offset   = $search['offset'];
        $per_page = $search['per_page'];
        $sWhere   = " orders.name LIKE '%" . $search['query'] . "%'";
        if ($search['location'] != "") {
            $sWhere .= " and orders.location = '" . $search['location'] . "'";
        }
        if ($search['status'] != "") {
            $sWhere .= " and orders.status = '" . $search['status'] . "'";
        }
        $sWhere .= " order by orders.id desc";
        $sql = "SELECT $campos FROM  $tables where $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
        
        $query    = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        $sql1     = "SELECT $campos FROM  $tables where $sWhere";
        $nums_row = $this->countAll($sql1);
        //Set counter
        $this->setCounter($nums_row);
        return $query;
    }
    function setCounter($counter)
    {
        $this->counter = $counter;
    }
    function getCounter()
    {
        return $this->counter;
    }
}
```

No sé como podría solucionarse, estoy aprendiendo un poco de programación web y me gustaria que me orientaran al respecto.

Muchas gracias por la lectura.

Comment: si te dice que el resultado es bool, entonces te llegó un valor de `false`, dado eso entonces el fallo anda aqui: **`$query = $this->mysqli->query($sql);`**

Comment: Haz un  `echo $sql1 ;` y revisa la consulta, puede que tenga algún error de sintaxis y por eso está fallando y devolviendo `false`, como bien dice @BetaM. Otra cosa, la propiedad se llama `num_rows`, por lo que esto es erróneo: `$count = $query->nums_row;`, debería ser **`$count = $query->num_rows;`** De todos modos, la mejor consulta, si se trata sólo de saber el número de filas, es un `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` me parece que se ha discutido sobre eso en otras preguntas. `num_rows` no es 100% seguro, a veces depende de si buffer o si no buffer, etc. y podría arrojar `0` aún habiendo filas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es un código libre de WARNINGs.

Replantéa con la siguiente estructura:

```
if($query = $this->mysqli->query($sql)){
    //lo que haces si hay registros
}else{
    // lo que haces si no hay registros
}
```